# How to override Enumerables sort method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a method that uses the functionality of Enumerables's `sort` method.

Imagine I have this data

```
data = [{project: 'proj', version: '1.1'}, {project: 'proj2', version: '1.11'}, {project: 'proj3', version: '1.2'}]
```

I want to be able to call the method like this:

```
data.natural_sort{|a,b| b[:version] <=> a[:version] }
```

The actual call that happens would achieve something like this:

```
data.sort{|a,b|  MyModule.naturalize_str(b[:version]) <=> MyModule.naturalize_str(a[:version]) }
```

Heres my current broken code:

```
Enumerable.module_eval do 

  def natural_sort(&block)
    if !block_given?
      block = Proc.new{|a,b| Rearmed.naturalize_str(a[:version]) <=> Rearmed.naturalize_str(b[:version])}
    end

    sort do |a,b| 
      a = Rearmed.naturalize_str(a)
      b = Rearmed.naturalize_str(b)
      block.call(a,b)
    end
  end

end
```

It throws an error because a and b are the hashes instead of the versions I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You're working at odds with yourself here. In your `natural_sort` block you're expecting hash objects, yet within the implementation you've explicitly cast `a` and `b` to be strings.

In Ruby there's two ways to sort, the `sort` method with `a,b` pairs, and the `sort_by` method which uses an intermediate sort form to do the comparisons. The `sort_by` approach is usually significantly faster since it applies the transform to each object once, while the `sort` method does it each time a comparison is done.

Here's a rewrite:

```
def natural_sort_by(&block)
  if (block_given?)
    sort_by do |o|
      Rearmed.naturalize_str(yield(o))
    end
  else
    sort_by do |o|
      Rearmed.naturalize_str(o)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can call it this way:

```
data.natural_sort_by { |o| o[:version] }
```

Comment: Actually, there are now two more ways to sort: `arr.min(arr.size)` and `arr.min_by(arr.size) {...}`. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's a sort/fetch deal, but it also follows the same style with an a/b version and one that does individual transforms.

Comment: I already have the natural_sort_by method but I am trying to implement the sort method as well.

Comment: Due to how these methods are defined it's not really practical to do what you want. The `sort` method expects a comparator and a result that's -1, 0 or 1. If you want your strings to behave in an unusual way, why not define a NaturalizedString class, write your own comparator, and use the regular `sort` method?